# How do I enforce an argument to be passed into the Shortcut from a WIX Toolset Configuration File?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I am using WIX Toolset to create an MSI.

I would like my shortcut to call the EXE with the "/config". How do I do that?

Essentially my program is, let's say, called "Program.exe". If I run it using the cmd, I would want to run it as the following:

```
Program.exe /config
```

How can I set the shortcuts created from the MSI installer so that it will call the above and not just

```
Program.exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Arguments](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/shortcut.html) attribute on the shortcut element to set any attributes you want to be passed to the application:

```
 <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" 
           Name="My Application Name"
           Description="My Application Description"
           Target="Program.exe"
           Arguments="/config"/>
```